# How to dockerize with NX (react and node app)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a nx workspace with 2 react app (client/admin) et 1 server with node.

For each, I have created a DockerFile and at the root of the project I have my docker-compose.yml.

My issue : when I use the command docker-compose up --build, the 3 app runs but for the react-app, I have a blank page whereas with the command nx serve <name_app>, we can see the app. Here is my code :

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY ./apps/front-client/src .

COPY ./package.json package.json

RUN npm install --production

EXPOSE 3000

USER node

CMD ["npx", "serve", "-s", ".", "-l", "3000"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  client:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/front-client/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./apps/front-client/src:/app/src
...
```

The root div doesn't have anything inside. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `WORKDIR` is set to `/home/node/app`, which means that the source is placed in `/home/nome/app/src`.

The `npx server -s . -l 3000` is executed in the `/home/nome/app/src`.

When you mount the volume in docker-compose, you are mounting the application on `/app/src`, but there is no `npx` serving from this folder.

Align both folders. By an unwritten convention the proper place is `/app/src` so change the build file to be `WORKDIR /app`

Comment: Thank your for your response. But, it's change nothing. It's the same result